# Removing words from text with separators in front(using Regex)

Tags: c#, regex

I need to remove words from the text with separators next to them. I already removed words but I don't know how I can remove separators at the same time. Any suggestions?
At the moment I have:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            string text = "";
            text = p.ReadText("Duomenys.txt", text);
            string[] wordsToDelete = { "Hello", "Thanks", "kinda" };
            char[] separators = { ' ', '.', ',', '!', '?', ':', ';', '(', ')', '\t' };
            p.DeleteWordsFromText(text, wordsToDelete, separators);
        }

        public string ReadText(string file, string text)
        {     
            text = File.ReadAllText(file);           
            return text;
        }

        public void DeleteWordsFromText(string text, string[] wordsToDelete, char[] separators)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(text);
            for (int i = 0; i < wordsToDelete.Length; i++)
            {
                text = Regex.Replace(text, wordsToDelete[i], String.Empty);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
```

The results should be:

```
how are you?
I am  good.
```

I have:

```
, how are you?
, I am . good.
```

Duomenys.txt

```
Hello, how are you? 
Thanks, I am kinda. good.
```

Comment: Aaaaaand ... what's the input? I don't have a `Duomenys.txt`.

Comment: Why do you need to use Regex?

Comment: I added .txt file

Comment: In the method `DeleteWordsFromText()` you never use `separators`. I guess it has something to do with that.

Comment: I don't know where can I insert them that if a word has a separator next to him delete it also.

Comment: Does "next to them" mean "immediately following"? And, do you want to remove the works only if a separator follows?

Comment: Yes. I would like to delete word not only if a separator follows.

Comment: @Thomas Weller, it's not a must to use Regex, I'm just experementing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may build a regex like

```
\b(?:Hello|Thanks|kinda)\b[ .,!?:;()    ]*
```

where `\b(?:Hello|Thanks|kinda)\b` will match any words to delete as whole words and `[ .,!?:;()    ]*` will match all your separators 0 or more times after the words to delete.

The [C# solution](https://ideone.com/d2HXK9):

```
char[] separators = { ' ', '.', ',', '!', '?', ':', ';', '(', ')', '\t' };
string[] wordsToDelete = { "Hello", "Thanks", "kinda" };
string SepPattern = new String(separators).Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("^", @"\^").Replace("-", @"\-").Replace("]", @"\]");
var pattern = $@"\b(?:{string.Join("|", wordsToDelete.Select(Regex.Escape))})\b[{SepPattern}]*";
// => \b(?:Hello|Thanks|kinda)\b[ .,!?:;()  ]*
Regex rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
// RegexOptions.IgnoreCase can be added to the above flags for case insensitive matching: RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled
DeleteWordsFromText("Hello, how are you?", rx);
DeleteWordsFromText("Thanks, I am kinda. good.", rx);
```

Here is the `DeleteWordsFromText` method:

```
public static void DeleteWordsFromText(string text, Regex p)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"---- {text} ----");
    Console.WriteLine(p.Replace(text, ""));
}
```

Output:

```
---- Hello, how are you? ----
how are you?
---- Thanks, I am kinda. good. ----
I am good.
```

**Notes**:

- `string SepPattern = new String(separators).Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("^", @"\^").Replace("-", @"\-").Replace("]", @"\]");` - it is a separator pattern that will be used inside a character class, and since only `^`, `-`, `\`, `]` chars require escaping inside a character class, only these chars are escaped
- `$@"\b(?:{string.Join("|", wordsToDelete.Select(Regex.Escape))})\b"` - this will build the alternation from the words to delete and will only match them as whole words.

**Pattern details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `Hello` - `Hello` word
  - `|` - or
  - `Thanks`- `Thanls` word
  - `|` - or
  - `kinda`- `kinda` word
- `)` - end of the group
- `\b` - word boundary
- `[ .,!?:;()  ]*` - any 0+ chars inside the character class.

See the [**regex demo**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3aHello%7cThanks%7ckinda%29%5cb%5b+.%2c!%3f%3a%3b%28%29++++%5d*&i=Hello%2c+how+are+you%3f+%0d%0aThanks%2c+I+am+kinda.+good.+&r=).

Answer (score 2):

You can build the regex like follows:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\b(" 
    + string.Join("|", wordsToDelete.Select(Regex.Escape)) + ")(" 
    + string.Join("|", separators.Select(c => Regex.Escape(new string(c, 1)))) + ")?");
```

Explanation:

- the \b at the start matches a word boundary. Just in case you get "XYZThanks"
- the next part builds a regex construct matching any of the wordsToDelete
- the last part builds a regex construct matching any of the separators; the trailing "?" is there because you said you want to replace the word also if no separator follows

Comment: It is a little bit confusing for me, where I should call this var?

Comment: var textWithoutWordsToDelete = regex.Replace(text, "");

Comment: If multiple separators are allowed, change the trailing ? to a *

Answer (score 1):

I would not use Regex. In 3 months from now, you'll not understand the Regex any more and fixing bugs is a hard thing then.

I would use simple loops. Everyone will understand:

```
public void DeleteWordsFromText(string text, string[] wordsToDelete, char[] separators)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    foreach (string word in wordsToDelete)
    {
        foreach(char separator in separators)
        {
            text = text.Replace(word + separator, String.Empty);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that it can be more than one separator for example `,` and ` `(space)

Comment: @D0mm: well, then your specs and/or test cases were not complete. Write more tests, do a red/green refactoring and you'll come to a good result.

Comment: @D0mm One of your examples contradicts this new interpretation: If multiple separators should be removed, "Thanks, I am kinda. good." would not produce "I am  good." (two spaces between m and g), but "I am good." (only one space).

Comment: @KlausGütter: citing OP: The results should be: `I am  good.` (with two spaces, although it does not show up as two spaces in comments) I don't think I'm gonna invest more time in questions where the requirements are not clear.